# Ayuda con Consultas Count mediante mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 tablas:

1. **asistencias**
   Columnas: (id,id_alumno,area,bimestre,estado,gestion,mes,dia)
2. **alumnos**
   Columnas: (id,apaterno,amaterno,nombres,nivel,curso,paralelo,gestion)

La asistencia se registra en la columna **estado**

- P=asistencia,L=licencia,F=falta,A=atrasos)

Necesito ayuda en la consulta para que me imprima asi en php:

```
apaterno | amaterno | nombres     |total P - total L - totalF - totalA
orosquito| miranda  | joseluicitox| ---8------2--------6---------8
```

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
$tabla1="alumnos";
$tabla2="asistencia";

$consult="SELECT $tabla1.id,$tabla1.apaterno,$tabla1.amaterno,$tabla1.nombres,$tabla1.nivel,$tabla1.curso,$tabla1.paralelo,$tabla1.gestion,$tabla2.id_asistencia,$tabla2.gestion,$tabla2.area,$tabla2.bimestre,$tabla2.estado,$tabla2.dia,$tabla2.mes FROM $tabla1,$tabla2 WHERE $tabla1.nivel='$nivel' AND $tabla1.curso='$curso' AND $tabla1.paralelo='$paralelo' AND $tabla2.gestion='$gestion' AND $tabla2.bimestre='$bimestre' AND $tabla2.area='$area' AND $tabla1.id=$tabla2.id_asistencia ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba esto:

```
  $tabla1="alumnos";
    $tabla2="asistencia";

    $consult="SELECT $tabla1.id,$tabla1.apaterno,$tabla1.amaterno,
    $tabla1.nombres,$tabla1.nivel,$tabla1.curso,
    $tabla1.paralelo,$tabla1.gestion,
    sum($tabla2.estado='P') as totalP,
    sum($tabla2.estado='L') as totalL,
    sum($tabla2.estado='F') as totalF,
    sum($tabla2.estado='A') as totalA
    FROM $tabla1
    INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.id=$tabla2.id_alumno
    WHERE $tabla1.nivel='$nivel' AND $tabla1.curso='$curso' AND
     $tabla1.paralelo='$paralelo' AND $tabla2.gestion='$gestion' AND
     $tabla2.bimestre='$bimestre' AND $tabla2.area='$area' 
     GROUP BY $tabla1.id";
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, logre realizar la consulta, ademas le aumente este código: count($tabla2.estado) as total -->para que me indique el total de días trabajados, gracias maestro,

Comment: Buenisimo Milton, recien veo la notificacion si llegas a necesitar algo con respecto a esta consulta no dudes en añadir un comentario para q pueda verlo.Saludos

Comment: Danilo necesito ayuda con consultas, publique otra pregunta pero todavia no recibo ayuda, puedes revisarlo porfa y orientarme?

Comment: Si milton ahi lo reviso :)

Answer (score 0):

lo que necesitas es agrupar la segunda tabla y utilizar case para agrupar los datos. Puedes hacerlo antes de `join` o durante la `join`. En cuanto a rendimiento, es mejor la segunda opción, pero te pongo aquí la primera porque creo que queda más claro el ejemplo de lo que tienes que hacer:

```
SELECT 
    $tabla1.id,
    $tabla1.apaterno,
    $tabla1.amaterno,
    $tabla1.nombres,
    $tabla1.nivel,
    $tabla1.curso,
    $tabla1.paralelo,
    $tabla1.gestion,
    TMP.totalP,
    TMP.totalL,
    TMP.totalF,
    TMP.totalA
FROM $tabla1
INNER JOIN (
    select 
        id_alumno,
        sum(case when estado='P' then 1 else 0 end) as totalP,
        sum(case when estado='L' then 1 else 0 end) as totalL,
        sum(case when estado='F' then 1 else 0 end) as totalF,
        sum(case when estado='A' then 1 else 0 end) as totalA
    FROM 
        $tabla2
    WHERE 
        $tabla2.gestion='$gestion' 
        AND $tabla2.bimestre='$bimestre' 
        AND $tabla2.area='$area' 
    GROUP BY id_alumno
)as Tmp
on TMP.id_alumno = $tabla1.id
WHERE $tabla1.nivel='$nivel' 
AND $tabla1.curso='$curso' 
AND $tabla1.paralelo='$paralelo'
```

La SQL la he montado sobre la marcha y puede que haya alguna cosa mal, pero la idea es esta.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Me manda un error inesperado en la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por su tiempo: pero  no logro realizar la consulta correcta e imprimir el resultado dejo el codigo completo de la busqueda
asistencias
Columnas: (id,id_alumno,area,bimestre,estado,gestion,mes,dia)
alumnos
Columnas: (id,apaterno,amaterno,nombres,nivel,curso,paralelo,gestion)
EL formulario de busque es en la misma pagina:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get" class="form-inline">
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="nivel" value="<?php echo $nivel;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="curso" value="<?php echo $curso;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="paralelo" value="<?php echo $paralelo;?>">

<input type="hidden" name="gestion" value="<?php echo $gestion;?>">
```

```
<div class="form-group">
   Bimestre:


 <select name="bimestre" class="form-control">
        <option value=" ">...</option>
        <option value="1BIM">1 Bimestre</option>
        <option value="2BIM">2 Bimestre</option>
        <option value="3BIM">3 Bimestre</option>
        <option value="4BIM">4 Bimestre</option>
   </select>   </div>  <div class="form-group">
       Materia:
   <select name="area" class="form-control">
        <option value=" ">Seleccionar</option>

<?php
include("../conexion.php");    
$consultaf="SELECT area FROM areas";
$resultado=$link->query($consultaf);
    while ($row=$resultado->fetch_array()) {
        $area=$row['area'];
    echo "<option value='".utf8_encode($area)."'>".utf8_encode($area)."</option>";
     //   echo $area;
    }

    ?>
   </select>
   </div>
    || <button type="submit" name="buscar" class="btn btn-warning "> Buscar Informe +</button>
</form>
```

Publico el codigo que funciono gracias maestros
Esta es el if donde se busca el informe en la misma página  e imprimir los resultados:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['buscar'])){ 
    //$name = $_POST['name'];
    include("../conexion.php");

    $nivel=$_GET['nivel'];
    $curso=$_GET['curso'];
    $paralelo=$_GET['paralelo']; 
    $gestion=$_GET['gestion'];
    $bimestre=$_GET['bimestre'];
    $area=$_GET['area'];
    ?>
    <form action="asis_areas_pdf.php" method="post">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"> 

                                <tbody>
     <tr> 
        <td colspan="6">RESUMEN DE ASISTENCIA  del Curso: <?php echo $curso." ".$paralelo." ".$nivel;?> </td>

     </tr>
<tr>

                                        <td>N°</td>
                                        <td class="warning"><H3>APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES</H3></td>
                                        <td class="danger">Asistencias</td>
                                        <td class="warning">Faltas</td>
                                        <td class="info">Licencias</td>                                
                                        <td class="success">Abandonos</td>
                                        <td class="success">Total</td>

                                    </tr>

    <?php
    $tabla1="alumnos";
    $tabla2="asistencia";

    $consulta="SELECT $tabla1.id,$tabla1.apaterno,$tabla1.amaterno,$tabla1.nombres,$tabla1.nivel,$tabla1.curso, $tabla1.paralelo,$tabla1.gestion,
        sum($tabla2.estado='P') as totalP,
        sum($tabla2.estado='L') as totalL,
        sum($tabla2.estado='F') as totalF,
        sum($tabla2.estado='A') as totalA,
        count($tabla2.estado)   as total
        FROM $tabla1 INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.id=$tabla2.id_alumno

        WHERE $tabla1.nivel='$nivel' AND $tabla1.curso='$curso' AND
         $tabla1.paralelo='$paralelo' AND $tabla2.gestion='$gestion' AND
         $tabla2.bimestre='$bimestre' AND $tabla2.area='$area'  
         GROUP BY $tabla1.id ORDER BY $tabla1.apaterno,$tabla1.amaterno,$tabla1.nombres ASC";
         if ($resultados=$link->query($consulta)) {
             while ($row=$resultados->fetch_array()) {

       $id=$row['id'];
       $apaterno=$row['apaterno'];
       $amaterno=$row['amaterno'];
       $nombres=$row['nombres'];
       $gestion=$row['gestion'];
       $totalP=$row['totalP'];
       $totalL=$row['totalL'];
       $totalF=$row['totalF'];
       $totalA=$row['totalA'];
       $total=$row['total'];

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "  <td>".$id."</td>
            <td>".$apaterno." ".$amaterno." ".$nombres."</td>
            <td>".$totalP."</td>
            <td>".$totalF."</td>
            <td>".$totalL."</td>
            <td>".$totalA."</td>
            <td>".$total."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }}
    ?>
```

Este es el código que funciono, gracias a todos por su ayuda, y el resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pues como veo tu consulta, parece que si te extrae los datos que deseas, si solo necesitas imprimirlo puedes hacerlo mediante un foreach, osea en ves del while has un foreach... 
intenta por colocar despues de la linea **$result=$link->query($consult);** lo siguente, a manera que se vea algo asi.....

```
$result=$link->query($consult);
$datos = $result->fetch_array();

foreach($datos as $_data){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <td>".$_data['apaterno']." ".$_data['amaterno']." ".$_data['nombres']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['totalP']."</td>"
    echo "<td>".$data['totalF']."</td>"
    echo "<td>".$data['totalL']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['totalA']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";


}
```

si todo va bien, eso deberia rellenarte la tabla con lo que deseas...
espero te sirva amigo... saludos